# Error while zipping file under Azure Local Storage "The directory Name is Invalid"

Tags: c#, azure, zip, angular-local-storage

Error Showing while try to zip file under Azure Local Storage.
I am trying to zip `.ps1` file to `<filename>.ps1.zip` and i am getting an error

> The directory name is invalid.

code:

```
       string scriptPath = Path.Combine(fileDirectoryPath, fileName);
       string destFilePath = string.Empty;
       List<string> zipFolderDetails = new List<string>();

       if (!File.Exists(scriptPath))
       {
           throw new Exception(string.Format("ZipFile : No file exists in the source path {0}", fileName));
       }

       string newDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(Utilities.GetLocalDirectoryScriptPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

       zipFolderDetails.Add(newDirectoryPath);      
       Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectoryPath);        
       destFilePath = newDirectoryPath + @"\" + fileName + ".zip";

       zipFolderDetails.Add(destFilePath);        
       //// Zipping the script file
       System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(scriptPath, destFilePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);  // <--- Exception here      
       return zipFolderDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we sorted out the issue. We were passing the `file path` as first parameter, but it should be the `directory path` where file needed to zip exists.

we changed the code like this and it works now

```
 System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, destFilePath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);  // <--- Exception here
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating the `destFilePath`, why can't you use like below.

```
destFilePath = Path.Combine(newDirectoryPath,fileName + ".zip");
```

which will give a correct path of the file you require.